# SideBar Not rendering anything on Dashboard Body: R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, rendering, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a shiny Dashboard which has two tabs in the side bar. **Tab1** is for importing a csv and **Tab2** is for showing the plots for the selected variable.

Tab2 has 1 select input option for selecting the variable for plot

**Problem**: After clicking on sidebar tabs, my dashboard body doesn't change. It is always showing me Tab1 Content i.e csv import results.
So despite of clicking on Tab2 in sidebar, nothing happens

Following is my script

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
#UI

sidebar=dashboardSidebar(width=200,
                     sidebarMenu( id="sidebar",
                                  menuItem("Data UpLoad", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("table"), 
                                           fileInput('file1','Choose CSV File',
                                                    accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))),

                                  menuItem("Uni Variate", tabName = "Uni", icon = icon("line-chart"),
                                           fluidRow(
                                          selectInput("options",label=h5("Select Column"),"")))))


body= dashboardBody(
 tabItems(
tabItem(tabName="dashboard",class='active',
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title="Data",solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
            div(style='overflow-x: scroll',tableOutput("table1"))))),

tabItem(tabName = "Uni",
        fluidRow(box(title="Plot",solidHeader = TRUE,plotOutput("plot1"))),
        h2("tab content"))))

dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title= "test"),sidebar,body)

#Server
server <- function(input, output,session) {
data_set <- reactive({
req(input$file1)
inFile <- input$file1
data_set1<-read.csv(inFile$datapath)
list(data=data_set1)
 })
 # updating select input of second tab in shiny side bar
observe({
 updateSelectInput(
  session,
  "options",
  choices = names(data_set()$data))})

# tab1
output$table1= renderTable({
de=as.data.frame(data_set()$data[1:7,])})

#tab2
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ggplot(data_set$data,aes(y=input$options,x=Prediction))+geom_histogram(binwidth=0.50, fill="blue") })
}
```

Every help is important!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is related to putting widgets on the sidebar, it takes them as sub-menus. Below are a couple of possible solution to have widgets on the sidebar depending if you want to hide them when are inactive.

**Option 1- widgets always visible**

```R
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width=200,
  sidebarMenu( id="sidebar",
    menuItem("Data UpLoad", icon = icon("table"), tabName = "dashboard"),
    div(
        fileInput('file1','Choose CSV File',
        accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))
    ),
    menuItem("Uni Variate", icon = icon("line-chart"), tabName = "Uni"),
    div(
      selectInput("options",label=h5("Select Column"),"")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="dashboard", class='active',
      box( title="Data",solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
        div(style='overflow-x: scroll', p("table1"))
      )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Uni",
      box(title="Plot", solidHeader = TRUE, p("plot1"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {}

shinyApp(dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title= "test"), sidebar, body), server = server)
```

**Option 2- widgets only visible when tab is active**

Please note that to show the correct tab on the body, the users must click on the sub-item.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width=200,
  sidebarMenu( id="sidebar",
      menuItem("data", icon = icon("table"), tabName = "dashboard",  
        menuSubItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          fileInput('file1','Choose CSV File',
          accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))
      )),
      menuItem("Uni Variate", icon = icon("line-chart"), tabName = "Uni", 
        menuSubItem( tabName = "Uni", 
          selectInput("options",label=h5("Select Column"),"")
      ))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="dashboard", class='active',
      box( title="Data",solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
        div(style='overflow-x: scroll', p("table1"))
      )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "Uni",
      box(title="Plot", solidHeader = TRUE, p("plot1"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {}

shinyApp(dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title= "test"), sidebar, body), server = server)
```

Comment: is it possible to provide input options for each menusubItem, under main Menuitem? If so, can you direct me to an example. table/plot does not render when I try to do this. Thank you